# Graph: Path with the maximum probability

Tags: python, graph

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enKO6.png)

I am trying to get the maximum probability path. I am getting the probability but not able to get the path(example: 1-2-3-4).

```
    from heapq import heappush, heappop

class Solution:
    def maxProbability(self, n, edges, succProb, start, end):
        
        graph = self.build_graph(edges, succProb)
        
        seen = set()
        
        max_heap = [(-1, start)]
        
        while max_heap:
            prob, cur = heappop(max_heap)
            
            # Maintain a seen set so that we do not visit a vertex we already processed
            # This is to avoid putting us in an infinite loop since a path from start to end is not always guaranteed
            seen.add(cur)
            if cur == end:
                return -prob
            for neigh, p in graph.get(cur, []):
                if not neigh in seen:
                    new_prob = -1 * abs(prob*p)
                    heappush(max_heap, (new_prob, neigh))

        # No path from start to end
        return 0
    
    def build_graph(self, edges, succProb):
        graph = {}
        for i in range(len(edges)):
            cur_edge = edges[i]
            cur_prob = succProb[i]
            graph.setdefault(cur_edge[0], []).append((cur_edge[1], cur_prob))
            graph.setdefault(cur_edge[1], []).append((cur_edge[0], cur_prob))
        return graph
```

Comment: Each element in the heap should also know that path that go you there.

Comment: @FrankYellin Can you please explain it via code. I'm not getting what are you trying to say

Comment: Each element in your heap is currently (probability, current).  Instead make it (probability, current, path-to-current).  Then when you reach the end, you'll know exactly how you got there.

Comment: @FrankYellin Can you please tell me how to get the path-to-current?

Comment: @FrankYellin Can you give a code snippet

Comment: You really need to be writing the code yourself.  When you pop an element off the heap, you'll know its probability, where you are, and how you got there.  When you look at each of that nodes neighbors, you'll know how you got to each of the neighbors: the same path that got you here, and then add the new neighbor.